# How to append lines of text into a Richtextbox at specific location/index?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

I have a lua script file in which I would like to add some new lines at specific locations.
So let's say we have the following text as an example:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3

line 8
line 9
line 10
```

I would like to insert some new lines after **line 3** and also a few additional lines before **line 8**
So far I've tried to index the lines but didn't found a way to use those indexes in order to write new lines of text.

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To textbox.Lines.Count - 1
    Dim x As Integer = i + 1
    Dim y As Integer = i - 1
    If textbox.Lines(i).Contains("line 3") Then
        textbox.Lines(x).Append("Line 4")
    End If
 Next
```

Comment: `textbox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine` is probably something you want to look at.  Just add Environment.NewLine with your string,   Use the `textbox.Select(range)` method and then `textbox.SelectedText = "something"` Be careful modifying the text like that while looping over it.  Might be safer to loop backwards to avoid the indexes getting messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else is facing the same obstacle,I found out that the required result is obtained by using the Input/Output library and threading library `Imports System.IO`,`Imports System.Threading`, combined with the following for loop:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To textbox.Lines.Length - 1
        Dim s As String = textbox.Lines(i)
        Dim index As Integer = s.IndexOf("line 3")
        If index > -1 Then
            Dim length As Integer = s.Length - index
            index += textbox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i)
            textbox.Select(index + length, 1)
            Thread.Sleep(1)
            SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
            textbox.Text = textbox.Text.Insert(textbox.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine,
                                       "line 4" & vbCrLf &
                                       "line 5 " & vbCrLf &
                                       "line 6" & vbCrLf &
                                       "line 7" & vbCrLf)
        End If
    Next
```